# Create groups of sequences whose element-wise difference is 1 in Scala?

Tags: scala

We have the following sequence of numbers: [19, 23, 24, 31, 126, 127, 155, 159, 160, 161]. We need to group this sequence according to difference between the neighboring values such that difference of values in each group would be equal to 1 if group size is > 1.

In Python, I would write something like:

```
outliers = [19, 23, 24, 31, 126, 127, 155, 159, 160, 161]

chains = [[i for i in list(map(itemgetter(1), g))]
           for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(outliers),
                                         lambda x: x[0]-x[1])]

# [[19], [23, 24], [31], [126, 127], [155], [159, 160, 161]]
```

Pretty neat. But how can this be done in Scala without falling back to loops with conditions? I have been trying to do something with `zipWithIndex` and `groupBy` methods by so far to no avail :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `fold` over the sequence, building the result as you go.

```
outliers.foldRight(List.empty[List[Int]]) {case (n, acc) =>
  if (acc.isEmpty) List(List(n))
  else if (acc(0)(0) == n+1) (n :: acc.head) :: acc.tail
  else List(n) :: acc
}
//res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(19), List(23, 24), List(31), List(126, 127), List(155), List(159, 160, 161))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if recursion can match with your conditions but it at last O(n).

```
def rec(source: List[Int], temp: List[Int], acc: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = source match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs => {
        if (xs.nonEmpty && xs.head - x == 1) rec(xs, temp :+ x, acc)
        else rec(xs, List(), acc :+ (temp :+ x))
    }
}
val outliers = List(19, 23, 24, 31, 126, 127, 155, 159, 160, 161)
rec(outliers, List[Int](), List[List[Int]]())
```